# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud, single-sign-on, pcf

I am struggling with this issue for last 10 days and couldn’t find help online. I am following the code as given in Pivotal SSO sample and sample works fine as expected, but when I copy the code to our project I am getting NoSuchBeanDefinition exception

```
2018-09-12T10:39:03.823-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.
OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetaiis available: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

And I my dependencies version as below

```
<org.springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<spring.security.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.ws.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud.dependencies.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.dependencies.version>
<spring-cloud-services.dependecies.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.dependecies.version>
```

Here is my code

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.implicit.ImplicitAccessTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;

@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId:placeholder}")
    private String clientId;

    // property set by spring-cloud-sso-connector
    @Value("${ssoServiceUrl:placeholder}")
    private String ssoServiceUrl;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        oauth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProviderChain());
    }   

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oa2prd, OAuth2ClientContext oa2cc) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oa2prd, oa2cc);
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProviderChain() {
        return new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider>asList(new OpenIDTokenProvider(),
                new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
                new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider()));
    }

@RequestMapping("/authorization_code")
    public String authCode(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        if (ssoServiceUrl.equals("placeholder")) {
            model.addAttribute("header", "Warning: You need to bind to the SSO service.");
            model.addAttribute("warning", "Please bind your app to restore regular functionality");
            return "configure_warning";
        }
        Map<?, ?> userInfoResponse = oauth2RestTemplate.getForObject("{ssoServiceUrl}/userinfo", Map.class,
                ssoServiceUrl);
        model.addAttribute("ssoServiceUrl", ssoServiceUrl);
        model.addAttribute("response", toPrettyJsonString(userInfoResponse));

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oauth2RestTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null) {
            model.addAttribute("access_token", toPrettyJsonString(parseToken(accessToken.getValue())));
            model.addAttribute("id_token",
                    toPrettyJsonString(parseToken((String) accessToken.getAdditionalInformation().get("id_token"))));
        }
        return "authorization_code";
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What confuses me, in the exception there is `OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetaiis`. Did you notice that there is a typo in it? Probably you didn't type everything in letter by letter, did you?

Comment: On the exception it is right as OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails, I copy pasted the exception, may be on formatting the post I might have made mistake. Thanks...

Comment: Do you have `spring-security-oauth2` on your classpath?

Comment: Yes I do have spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar in my classpath. I suspect spring cloud and spring boot version conflict might be a reason. Because the Pivotal sample application works fine. Thanks